# Netty benchmarks and other promotional information

Tags: netty

I'm looking for the Netty benchmarks and other promotional information so that I can convince the team that Netty is the way to go. I don't need any convincing myself :)

The old site used to have more info on this sort of thing but the old site appears to be gone.

Can anyone send me links or more information? Can the site be updated?

Thanks to Nicholas for providing some benchmarks. It would also great to see a list of which open source projects and commercial organizations are using Netty. I think this information used to be available but I can't find it online anymore.

It is important for those of us who have to convince skeptical team members and for noobs who know little about what a fantastic project this is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With several provisos, caveats and disclaimers, I put forth these [hotly contested benchmarks](http://vertxproject.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/vert-x-vs-node-js-simple-http-benchmarks/) from [vert.x](http://vertx.io/) which uses Netty under the covers. Not exactly what you're looking for, but the benchmark and associated test harness may be useful for comparison purposes.

I will be sure to follow this question and see what else comes in.